# Java : ByteBuffer allocateDirect Allocate direct allocate more than demanding

Tags: java

Im using allocateDirect to make my ByteBuffer a direct buffer, my width is 984 and my height is 1312, when calling:

```
 buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mDrawViewport.width * mDrawViewport.height * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
```

I think i will get 5164032 bytes for this buffer, i have check the capacity and limit of my buffer and they are 5164032 bytes, but when getting byte array by calling "buffer.array()" and get it's length, i get 5164039 bytes.

What is the problem here?

Thank for reading this post.

Comment: Trying to obtain an array from a *direct* byte buffer using the `array()` method will cause an `UnsupportedOperationException`. If this works for you, then there is something wrong...

Comment: @Marco13 Not necessarily. Documentation says that it's unspecified whether or not it has a backing array.

Comment: @Bubletan I was talking about the Oracle VM here. The question should be updated when a "uncommon" VM is used.

Comment: Hi @huy, were you able to get the root cause of this issue ?